# Multiple @UniqueEntity annotations at one entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, constraints

I have an entity which has two unique indexes. I like to add two **[UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)** constraints to the entity for validation purposes.

The given entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sample", uniqueConstraints={
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"user_id", "hash"}),
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"user_id", "name"})
 * })
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"user", "jobSearch"}, message="duplicate_hash")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"user", "name"}, message="duplicate_name")
 */
class SampleEntity
{
    // ...
}
```

The problem: only the last `@UniqueEntity` gets respected. So only a duplicate key for `user` and `name` gets recognized or vice-versa only for `user` and `jobSearch` if I switch the UniqueEntity annotations.

Is there any solution to cover two unique indexes with `@UniqueEntity`?

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up writing a custom validation to prevent form being submitted, if this might work for you I can post some code

Comment: @Rooneyl yeah that absolutely works for me... would be nice if you could share your findings/code.

Answer (score 2):

I got around this by using a custom validation. Sample code;
in *src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraints*

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/UniqueCodeName.php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class UniqueCodeName extends Constraint
{
    public $message = "must have a unique code and name.";

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'code_name';
    }
}
```

And

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/UniqueCodeName.php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint,
    Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class UniqueCodeNameValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) 
    {
        $this->entityManager = $em;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $formCampaign = $this->context->getRoot()->getData();
        $code_name = $formCampaign->getClient()->getCode().$formCampaign->getCode();
        $campaigns = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Campaign')->findBy(
            [
                'code' => $code_name, 
                'name' => $formCampaign->getName()
            ]
        );

        if ($campaigns) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Service declaration for constraint;

```
services:
    validator.unique.campaign_code_name:
            class: AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueCodeNameValidator
            tags:
                - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: code_name }
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Sample of entity class;

```
<?php // src/AppBundle/Enitiy/Campaign.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as AppAssert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM,
    Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity,
    Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use \DateTime;

/**
 * Campaign
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="campaign")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CampaignRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"code", "name"})
 */
class Campaign 
{
    // other stuff

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=11, groups={"create", "update"})
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/\d/", match=true, message="Code must be numeric", groups={"create", "update"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"create", "update"})
     * @AppAssert\UniqueCodeName(groups={"create", "update"})
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your code :-). It inspired me to write a `ChainValidator` which can hold n other Validators. This way it was possible to add mutliple UniqueEntityValidators. I'll post the code in about a minute

Answer (score 1):

I had the idea to create a `ChainValidator` which can hold *n* other validators:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sample", uniqueConstraints={
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"user_id", "hash"}),
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"user_id", "name"})
 * })
 * @Chain(constraints={
 *     @UniqueEntity(fields={"user", "hash"}, message="duplicate_hash"),
 *     @UniqueEntity(fields={"user", "name"}, message="duplicate_name")
 * })
 */
class SampleEntity
{
    // ...
}
```

This way it's possible to add *n* `UniqueEntity` validators to one entity.

When I googled it to find out if someone else already had this idea. I found this gist: https://gist.github.com/rybakit/4705749 which is basically exactly what I need and in the end implemented in a very similar way.